# Problem in ploting multiple lines in a graph for precision recall curve

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, scikit-learn, deep-learning

I am trying to plot precision recall curve for multiclass in one figure for this purpose I used below code

```
def plot_prc(y_test, y_score, N_classes):
    precision = dict()
    recall = dict()
    average_precision = dict()
    for i in range(N_classes):
        precision[i], recall[i], _ = precision_recall_curve(y_test[:, i],y_score[:, i])
        average_precision[i] = average_precision_score(y_test[:, i], y_score[:, i])
    for i in range(N_classes):
        plt.plot(recall[i], precision[i], lw=2, label='class {}'.format(i,average_precision[i] ))
        #plt.plot(recall[i], precision[i], lw=2, label='class {}'.format(i))
        plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], 'k--')
        plt.xlabel("recall")
        plt.ylabel("precision")
        plt.legend(loc="best")
        plt.title("precision vs. recall curve")
        plt.show()
```

but i am getting multiple figures for different classes.I could not point it out what is error in my code. 
[I got a single line like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gJeg.png)

[for class 1 curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0Jyf.png)

but i want look like this figure
[will be multiple line in a figure for all class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XH6K.png)

I will appreciate any kind of help regarding this problem.

Comment: Put `plt.show()` outside the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second for-loop which is iterated for each class, if plt.show() is included in the loop, then the plot shows up for single class every time instead of plotting the graphs of all the classes in the same plot. So the solution for this problem should be to put the plt.show() out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are plotting the lines inside the for loop but your `plt.show()` function is also
inside the `for loop`, so this will result in plotting of result of last for loop cycle.
Put your `plt.show()` function outside the `for loop`.